# How do I get my custom JPanel to show in another class?

Tags: java, swing, windowbuilder

I am writing a small program just for personal use to double check strategies on a mobile based game. I created a `Board` class and frame and whatnot, then I created a new Panel class in my package (I use Eclipse). I figured it would be as simple as creating the two and implementing the Panel and adding it to the main frame of the `Board` class. Alas, I was mistaken.

**TubePanel - my secondary panel**

```java
package ballSort;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerListModel;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class TubePanel extends JPanel {
    
    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */
    public TubePanel() {
        setBackground(new Color(47, 79, 79));
        setBounds(10, 10, 30, 40);
    }
}
```

**This is an excerpt from my main Board class.... **

```java
    panel_1 = new JPanel();
    panel_1.setBounds(118, 164, 726, 466);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel_1);

    JButton btnNewButton_1 = new JButton("X");
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            frame.dispose();
        }
    });
    btnNewButton_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 89));
    btnNewButton_1.setBounds(10, 122, 85, 124);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton_1);
}
    
public void Create(int tubes) {
    TubePanel tube = new TubePanel();
    panel_1.add(tube);

    System.out.println(tube);
    System.out.println(panel_1);
}
```

Am I the idiot here? This should've worked, as far as I'm concerned, but clearly I know not the ways of the Java. [Only been coding java for 4 years.] Anyway the problem is that it doesn't show the *tubePanel*.
It doesn't give any errors either so I had to use Sysout to see if there was anything wrong with it and `panel_1` for a comparison...

```
ballSort.TubePanel[,10,10,30x40,**invalid**,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
javax.swing.JPanel[,118,164,726x466,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
```

Aside from the **invalid** (to which I tried to follow it to its root, I couldn't figure it out) there's nothing different from *panel_1* compared to *tube*.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the lesson entitled [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) from trail *Creating a GUI With JFC/Swing* which is part of Oracle's Java tutorials.

The default layout of the content pane of a `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. When you add a component to the content pane, it gets added to the center area of the `BorderLayout`. The center area (and all other areas) of `BorderLayout` can only contain a single component. So when you add two components to the center area, only one will be displayed. Refer to method [add(Component, Object)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#add-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-) in class `java.awt.Container`

So study the layout managers and decide which is suitable.